# android - Cache de imagens e mostrar listview

Tags: android, sqlite, volley

Boa tarde amigos,
é o seguinte: vou usar a Volley para pegar os dados do webservice, e assim gravo a lista no meu BD local com SQlite.

Nesse webservice virá um JSON com itens, cada item tem seus dados e uma imagem. Eu preciso guarda essa imagem em cache para mostrar em uma listview e posteriormente em uma tela de detalhes. No futuro o usuário irá limpar esses itens, limpando assim as imagens deles também.

Pois bem, como eu posso salvar essas imagens em cache e vincular a cada item salvo no meu BD?

**EDIT 1**

Eu vou, em 90%, estar offline. Só vou ficar online para sicronizar e baixar os itens atualizados do servidor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como você adotará diversos recursos para facilitar o desenvolvimento, utilize o **[Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)** e deixe ele gerenciar isto para você.

Por meio de um Target você consegue interceptar e guardar a imagem. Exemplo:

```
public class MeuTarget implements Target
{
    private final WeakReference<ContentResolver> resolver;
    private final String name;
    private final String desc;

    public TargetPhoneGallery(ContentResolver r, String name, String desc)
    {
        this.resolver = new WeakReference<ContentResolver>(r);
        this.name = name;
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad (Drawable arg0)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded (Bitmap bitmap, LoadedFrom arg1)
    {
       //sua implementacao para guardar o bitmap.
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed (Drawable arg0)
    {
    }
}

Picasso.with(context).load(image[position]).into(new MeuTarget(view.getContentResolver(), "nome-imagem", "descricao"));
```

Comment: Com ele eu consigo relacionar meus dados salvo no banco com as imagens?

Comment: @LuanGabriel editei para ajudar. Na documentação constam mais detalhes.

Comment: Ah, esqueci de mencionar: eu tenho que mostrar essas imagens offline. Só vou conectar com a internet quando eu sincronizar com o servidor e baixar os itens.

Comment: Indiferente. Com o picasso você consegue esse resultado.

Comment: Picasso realmente resolveu. Utilizei o atributo                            `.networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)` também.